# Listas únicas com pelo menos 2 elementos de diferença

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Considerando os números:

```
01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25
```

Como faço para gerar listas de 15 itens (números citados acima), sendo que elas precisam ter pelo menos 2 itens de diferença entre si. Por exemplo:

```
01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15
01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,17,18
01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,20,22
01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,21,25
```

Reparem no final, eu mudei apenas os últimos 2 itens de cada lista, eles são únicos, não existem nas demais listas. Como fazer isso na prática, sendo que os 2 itens de diferença podem estar em qualquer posição?

Comment: Procure sobre [Análise Combinatória e Funções Enumerativas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinat%C3%B3ria). Link que fala sobre um problema parecido: [Como listar as combinações de uma binomial simples](https://www.devmedia.com.br/analise-combinatoria-como-listar-as-combinacoes-de-uma-binomial-simples/1479)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Atualização 1

Outro jeito de chegar ao resultado é removendo os elementos já adicionados nas listas:

```
import random

def gera_lista(qnt):
  listas = []
  numeros = random.sample(range(1, 100), 25)
  # Sorteia 13 elementos da lista `numeros`
  primeiros = random.sample(numeros, 13)
  # Pega a diferença entre a lista `numeros` e a lista `primeiros`
  # e define como novo valor da lista `numeros`
  numeros = list(set(numeros).difference(set(primeiros)))
  for _ in range(0, qnt):
    # Se o numero de elementos na lista: `numeros` for
    # igual a zero para o laço `for`
    if len(numeros) == 0: break
    # Sorteia os dois ultimos numeros e
    # depois cria uma nova lista com a junção da
    # lista: `numeros` com a lista: `sorteados`
    sorteados = random.sample(numeros, 2)
    lista = primeiros + sorteados
    # Adiciona a nova lista na lista: `listas`
    listas.append(lista)
    # Remove os numeros sorteados da lista: `numeros`
    [numeros.remove(x) for x in sorteados if x in numeros]
  return listas

print(gera_lista(20))
```

[Veja funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/@wellmotta/302685-1-stackoverflow) e também [criei um Gist no GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/wellmotta/d87b256fcb3f9dd2b6226e780fccaf43)

---

Crie uma função e utilize [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.sample) para sortear dois números e [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) para verificar se estes dois elementos contem na lista.

```
def diferente(lista):
    # Sortea dois números
    a, b = random.sample(numeros, 2)
    # Verifica se 'a' e 'b' não esta na lista
    # se estiver, chama a função novamente, caso contrário
    # adiciona
    [lista.extend([a,b]) if (a not in chain.from_iterable(listas)) and (b not in chain.from_iterable(listas)) else diferente(lista)]
```

declare uma lista vazia:

```
nova_lista = []
```

Sorteie os 13 primeiros números e armazena em uma variável:

```
# Sorteia os 13 primeiros elementos
primeiros = random.sample(numeros, 13)
```

depois dentro do `for`, adicione os primeiros elementos na nova lista, chame a função para adicionar os outros dois e de um reset na lista:

```
# Adiciona os primeiros elementos na nova lista
nova_lista.extend(primeiros)
# Adiciona os outros dois elementos
diferente(nova_lista)
listas.append(nova_lista)
# Reseta a lista
nova_lista = []
```

Veja o código completo:

```
import random
from itertools import chain

numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
listas = []

def gera_lista(qnt):
    nova_lista = []
    # Sorteia os 13 primeiros elementos
    primeiros = random.sample(numeros, 13)
    for i in range(0, qnt):
        # Adiciona os primeiros elementos na nova lista
        nova_lista.extend(primeiros)
        # Adiciona os outros dois elementos
        diferente(nova_lista)
        listas.append(nova_lista)
        nova_lista = []

def diferente(lista):
    # Sortea dois números
    a, b = random.sample(numeros, 2)
    # Verifica se 'a' e 'b' não esta na lista
    # se estiver, chama a função novamente, caso contrário
    # adiciona
    [lista.extend([a,b]) if (a not in chain.from_iterable(listas)) and (b not in chain.from_iterable(listas)) else diferente(lista)]

gera_lista(5)
print(listas)
```

[Veja funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/@wellmotta/302685-stackoverflow) e também [criei um Gist no GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/wellmotta/e79bb34f0cbfadc8977f8abb595cd662)

### Referências

- [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.sample)
- [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

Comment: Interessante! Obrigado pela ajuda. Mas como faço para gerar os números de forma que seja adicionado qualquer número entre os 25 e não apenas os 13 primeiros? Exemplo:

`02,04,05,06,09,10,11,12,13,15,17,18,19,22,25`

Comment: Fiz isso mais ai gera apenas 1 lista. Eu não sei bem, mas eu acho que teria que ir armazenando cado item, quantas vezes saiu e em qual determinada lista. Mais ai eu não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: Veja agora como está

Comment: Excelente! Agora está perfeito. Só queria fazer para gerar todas as combinações possíveis,sem limitar a quantidade de resultados (listas). Eu tentei colocar um número grande ou até adaptar o for, mas dá erro `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`